# jquery function onclick event not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following snippet -

```
<div class="w3-row" >
    <div class="w3-col"></div>
    <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;" >

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#pru-exam-timer").click(
                function(){
                    startRealTest();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <!--<button id="pru-exam-timer" onclick="startRealTest();return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Start Real Test</button>-->
        <input id="pru-exam-timer" type="submit" value="Start Real Test">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Start Mock Test</button>-->
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col"></div>
</div>
```

The function `startRealTest()` is getting called properly but it is NOT getting called at all once  I move the code within  tags to a separate .js file. Also, it important to note that startRealTest() function is getting called properly(even when it is in a separate .js file) when I invoke it through button line

Any pointers please , what could be going wrong here.

Comment: refer your file in html page (drag it)

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: As for your problem, make sure the file containing the function call is loaded after jquery.js and after the one defining the function (put the `script` tags in that order).

Comment: .js file is loaded after jquery.js

Comment: were you want to move your code? code snippet in question is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script is getting Loaded before the Tag is getting loaded. SO at the time of Loading there is no tag with specified ID. Hence it is not working.

```
<div class="w3-row" >
<div class="w3-col"></div>
<div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;"/>
<input id="pru-exam-timer" type="submit" value="Start Real Test">
</div>
<div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;">
</div>
<div class="w3-col"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pru-exam-timer").click(
            function(){
                startRealTest();
            });
        });
   </script>
 </div>`
```

Please try the above snippet.It will work

Comment: I believe that is why we have jQuery(document).on('ready',function ()
{ ....As I said earlier this anyways works but when I put call the function startRealTest() located in a separate .js file it is not getting called.

Comment: Can you tell me where are you including your script source for the separate js File ?

Comment: in the html source files itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a syntax error in your js, the error is

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

You should do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#pru-exam-timer").click(function(){
     alert('Its Working!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-row" >
    <div class="w3-col"></div>
    <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;" >


        <!--<button id="pru-exam-timer" onclick="startRealTest();return false;" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Start Real Test</button>-->
        <input id="pru-exam-timer" type="submit" value="Start Real Test">
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Start Mock Test</button>-->
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work by including the  tags as follows:

```
  <script src="http:....assets/js/prudentquizy.js" type="text/javascript">       </script>
 <div class="w3-row" >
 <div class="w3-col"></div>
 <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;text-align:center;font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;" >
    <input id="pru-exam-timer" type="submit" value="Start Real Test">
     </div>
     <div class="w3-col" style="vertical-align:center;    text-align:center;       font-size:23px;padding-top:25px;padding-bottom:25px;">

     </div>
     <div class="w3-col"></div>
</div>
```

The file prudentquizy.js has jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
            jQuery("#pru-exam-timer").click(
            function(){
                    startRealTest();    });
            });
```

This is perplexing because even earlier when I saw the html source it was there in the  tag.